# Reason for libboost_log_setup.a library?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

In the latest Boost 1.54 release I see [Boost.Log](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) library appeared. When I compile whole Boost 1.54 I see that for the Log library it produced 2 binaries:

- libboost_log.a
- libboost_log_setup.a

What is the reason for the `libboost_log_setup.a` library? When should I link it?

Comment: Besides, it would be nice to know why it's so big :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

libboost_log_setup contains extended support for logging.

For example, when using a formatter into your logging activities, you'll require this library.

By the way, note that you need to link libboost_log_setup BEFORE libboost_log, since the first depends on the last.
In other words, you need to place libboost_log_setup before libboost_log in the libraries setup.